# Infinite x and y scroll of uiview

Tags: objective-c, scroll, infinite

I have a 1500x1500 uiview with a 1500x1500 uiimageview inside centered in the main view of my iPad project. The code below will infinitely scroll side to side when you tilt the iPad in either direction. What I have been trying to do is get it to also scroll up and down seamlessly like the side to side. Unfortunately it seems to jump around and not be correct. Any ideas?

```
    - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel
didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    accelX = acceleration.x;
    accelY = acceleration.y;
    accelZ = acceleration.z;

    int speed;
    speed = 1;

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x+delta.x,imageView.center.y+delta.y);

    // allows infinite side-to-side scrolling
    if (imageView.center.x > 748){
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(512,384);
        NSLog(@"Greater than 780");
    }
    if (imageView.center.x < 284){
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(519,384);
        NSLog(@"Less than 284");
    }

    if (accelY > 0.01f) {delta.x = -speed;}
    else if (accelY < -0.01f) {delta.x = speed;}
    else if (0.01f < accelY > -0.01f){delta.x = 0;}

// should allow up/down infinite scrolling but does not - it is very jumpy when it resets
//  if (imageView.center.y > 748){imageView.center = CGPointMake(512,384);}
//  if (imageView.center.y < 284){imageView.center = CGPointMake(518,752);}

// this makes it run only with the angle of the iPad the way I want it
//  if (accelZ > -0.5f) {delta.y = speed;}
//  else if (accelZ < -0.1f) {delta.y = -speed;}
//  else if (0.3f < accelZ > -0.3f){delta.y = 0;}

}
```